# How to import and merge existing site from svn to git?

Tags: importing-exporting, version-control

I'm working with a site that has been using Subversion for version control and we'd like to swtich to using git instead. It seems like it would make the most sense to clone the [Drupal project git respository](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git) from [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/), checkout the branch that represents the version closest to the existing site, create a new branch from that point and then somehow merge the existing svn repository into that branch. Is it possible to do that last step, to avoid losing the svn history?

For what it's worth, in [one of the Pantheon demo screencasts](http://vimeo.com/14755236) they're doing something similar (around the 3 minute mark). It looks like they are starting with a backup of the site though, rather than importing a repository and its associated history.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any advantages to being "in sync" with drupal git repo unless you're "chasing head."

I would just convert your current SVN repo to git. You can create a new branch that tracks drupal git and merge that branch in occasionally (if your directory structures match) or just download the final release packages and copy them into your directory and commit the changes.